# onclick not working on Android Emulator (ionic framework)

Tags: ionic-framework

Steps:
1. ionic start Hello blank

2. Add button to the index.html

```html
 <ion-content>
        <button class="button" onclick="javascript:alert('x');">Try Click</button>
</ion-content>
```

3. inside hello dir: ionic run android
4. click the 'Try Click' button. Nothing happens.

Info:
Emulator: Android 4.4.2 API 19

Comment: use `ng-click`... common issue.. Try avoid using jquery elements..use angular elements..

Comment: even the simple anchor is not working: <a href="#" onclick="javascript:alert('x')">Click Link</a>

Answer (score 0):

change it to ng-click and in general it is better to call a function.

You should separate your logic from your views.

example HTML

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController">
   <ons-button ng-click="yourFunction()">Click Me!</ons-button>
</div>
```

JS

```
.controller('SomeController', function () {
   $scope.yourFunction = function () {
      console.log("x is triggered");
      alert('x');
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <ion-content>
        <button class="button" ng-click="javascript:alert('x');">Try Click</button>
</ion-content>
```

ng-click instead of onclick..

Comment: the ng-click is not working as well. I tried <a href="#" onclick="javascript:alert('x')">Click Link</a>, the alert does not show. But it works when the link is outside the ionic directives